# How to use Android Shared Preferences (using delegation) in kotlin without assigning value to variable

Tags: android, kotlin, delegation

Using the below code for getting and setting preference value. I am forced to use var "pref1" for that. Using multiple variables can be a heavy process. Every time while getting or setting sharedPreferences using a variable is compulsory. Is there any other way to use this without declaring variables???

```
var pref1 by stringPref("Pref1","value1")
var prefValue by stringPref("Pref1")
```

```
abstract class PrefDelegate<T>(val prefName: String?, val prefKey: String) {
    protected val prefs: SharedPreferences by lazy {
        if (getAppContext() != null) 
            if (prefName != null) getAppContext().getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) else PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getAppContext())
        else
            throw IllegalStateException("Context was not initialized. Call PrefDelegate.init(context) before using it")
    }

    abstract operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T
    abstract operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T)

}

fun makeStringPref(prefKey: String, defaultValue: String? = null) {
    var count by stringPref(prefKey,defaultValue)
}


fun stringPref(prefKey: String, defaultValue: String? = null)= StringPrefDelegate(null, prefKey, defaultValue)
fun stringPref(prefName: String, prefKey: String, defaultValue: String? = null) = StringPrefDelegate(prefName, prefKey, defaultValue)


class StringPrefDelegate(prefName: String?, prefKey: String, val defaultValue: String?) : PrefDelegate<String?>(prefName, prefKey) {
    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) = prefs.getString(prefKey, defaultValue) 
    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: String?) = prefs.edit().putString(prefKey, value).apply() 
}



fun intPref(prefKey: String, defaultValue: Int = 0) = IntPrefDelegate(null, prefKey, defaultValue)
fun intPref(prefName: String, prefKey: String, defaultValue: Int = 0) = IntPrefDelegate(prefName, prefKey, defaultValue)


class IntPrefDelegate(prefName: String?, prefKey: String, val defaultValue: Int) : PrefDelegate<Int>(prefName, prefKey) {
    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) = prefs.getInt(prefKey, defaultValue)
    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: Int) = prefs.edit().putInt(prefKey, value).apply() 
}
```

Comment: Do you want to prevent setting `val prefName: String?` every time? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Or are you talking about setting default value every time?

Comment: I want to prevent setting val prefName: String? every time